# Updated media queries for high resolution devices

Tags: css, cross-browser, media-queries

Keeping in mind progressive enhancement, browser/device support, 'mobile-first', and multiple flavors of iOS 'retina' display ratios...
Would this target correctly and still provide legacy support?

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { @import '2x'; }
```

I've seen this it looks almost TOO easy:

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and ( min-resolution: 192dpi) { @import '2x'; }
```

Reference for min-resolution: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#resolution

Comment: does my answer below help you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Since safari makes use of the webkit engine and so does android, the second block of code targets the whole Apple lineup and any desktop or mobile device with chrome or the newer versions of Opera that make use of the Blink engine (a fork of Webkit). The first block of code targets all web browsers as well the previously mentioned.

And a tip for the code that goes within the brackets, you can put the code from the 2x.css file straight into those brackets. Not only will the browser parse and render the css faster because it is right after the media queries, but it will also prevent the use of @import statements which slow down the browser even more.

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and ( min-resolution: 192dpi) {
    body {
        background: brown;
    }

    #wrapper {
        background: green;
    } 
}
```

This is what you want to do when using media queries, and avoid using `only screen` and commas in between each specification; the `and` suffices.

Comment: Updated '2x' media query CSS: @media screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) { ... } [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#-moz-device-pixel-ratio)

Comment: there's nothing wrong with using dpi is there? dppx and dpi are just two ways of measuring the same thing?

Comment: dpi a bit 'old school,' and is more for general use (sometimes used when describing print), where as dppx is specifically for display screens. dpi is considered for compatibility with 'older' browsers. Browsers are moving towards making dppx the standard (e.g. Firefox, Chrome, etc.)